# I can not figure out why I keep getting this error

Tags: javascript, json

I keep getting this error code on different lines every time I run this script , but I can not figure out why? here is the source code. I will answer any questions and or can respond quickly . I'm not sure what other details to give.

```js
$(function() {

  var

    bungieId = checkParams('bungieId'),
    destinyId = checkParams('destinyId'),
    joined = checkParams('joined'),
    checkName = function(name, list) {

      var m = false; // flag
      console.log('Checking list for ' + name + '...');

      // loop through clan usernames and check for a match
      $.each(list, function(i) {
        // make case insensitve
        if (name.toLowerCase() === list[i].toLowerCase()) {
          console.log('Confirmed: ' + list[i]);
          m = true;
        }
      });

      if (m) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }

    };

  if (bungieId && destinyId && joined) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://www.bungie.net/Platform/Destiny2/2/Account/" + destinyId + "/Character/0/Stats/UniqueWeapons/",
      headers: {
        "X-API-Key": apiKey
      },
      success: function(data) {
        if (data.ErrorStatus === 'Success') {





          Telesto = data.Response.weapons[0].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            TheHuckleberry = data.Response.weapons[1].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            RatKing = data.Response.weapons[2].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            Anarchy = data.Response.weapons[3].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            SUROSRegime = data.Response.weapons[4].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            Sunshot = data.Response.weapons[5].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            DARCI = data.Response.weapons[6].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            Borealis = data.Response.weapons[7].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            Thunderlord = data.Response.weapons[8].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            PolarisLance = data.Response.weapons[9].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            Crimson = data.Response.weapons[10].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            FightingLion = data.Response.weapons[11].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            TractorCannon = data.Response.weapons[12].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            LeMonarque = data.Response.weapons[13].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            GravitonLance = data.Response.weapons[14].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            VigilanceWing = data.Response.weapons[15].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            BlackTalon = data.Response.weapons[16].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            TheColony = data.Response.weapons[17].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            SleeperSimulant = data.Response.weapons[18].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            HardLight = data.Response.weapons[19].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            Merciless = data.Response.weapons[20].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            SkyburnersOath = data.Response.weapons[21].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            PrometheusLens = data.Response.weapons[22].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            Malfeasance = data.Response.weapons[23].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            OutbreakPerfected = data.Response.weapons[24].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            Jötunn = data.Response.weapons[25].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            WishEnder = data.Response.weapons[26].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            SweetBusiness = data.Response.weapons[27].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            Coldheart = data.Response.weapons[28].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            TheWardcliffCoil = data.Response.weapons[29].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            LegendofAcrius = data.Response.weapons[30].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            Wavesplitter = data.Response.weapons[31].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            WhisperoftheWorm = data.Response.weapons[32].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            Arbalest = data.Response.weapons[33].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            TwoTailedFox = data.Response.weapons[34].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            Sturm = data.Response.weapons[35].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            Riskrunner = data.Response.weapons[36].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            IzanagisBurden = data.Response.weapons[37].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            TheChaperone = data.Response.weapons[38].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            LordofWolves = data.Response.weapons[39].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            TheProspector = data.Response.weapons[40].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            Thorn = data.Response.weapons[41].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            TheLastWord = data.Response.weapons[42].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            Cerberus = data.Response.weapons[43].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            WorldlineZero = data.Response.weapons[44].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            TheQueenbreaker = data.Response.weapons[45].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            BadJuju = data.Response.weapons[46].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            Lumina = data.Response.weapons[47].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            LegendofAcrius = data.Response.weapons[48].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            TheJadeRabbit = data.Response.weapons[49].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            AceofSpades = data.Response.weapons[50].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            TrinityGhoul = data.Response.weapons[51].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            Truth = data.Response.weapons[52].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue,
            MIDAMultiTool = data.Response.weapons[53].values.uniqueWeaponKills.basic.displayValue;



          $('#player-AceofSpades').text(AceofSpades);
          $('#player-TheJadeRabbit').text(TheJadeRabbit);
          $('#player-TrinityGhoul').text(TrinityGhoul);
          $('#player-SweetBusiness').text(SweetBusiness);
          $('#player-TheWardcliffCoil').text(TheWardcliffCoil);
          $('#player-Wavesplitter').text(Wavesplitter);
          $('#player-TheQueenbreaker').text(TheQueenbreaker);
          $('#player-PrometheusLens').text(PrometheusLens);
          $('#player-Two-TailedFox').text(Two - TailedFox);
          $('#player-TheJadeRabbit').text(TheJadeRabbit);
          $('#player-DARCI').text(DARCI);
          $('#player-TheChaperone').text(TheChaperone);
          $('#player-Lumina').text(Lumina);
          $('#player-LegendofAcrius').text(LegendofAcrius);
          $('#player-GravitonLance').text(GravitonLance);
          $('#player-SleeperSimulant').text(SleeperSimulant);
          $('#player-SkyburnersOath').text(SkyburnersOath);
          $('#player-Merciless').text(Merciless);
          $('#player-Thorn').text(Thorn);
          $('#player-LeMonarque').text(LeMonarque);
          $('#player-BlackTalon').text(BlackTalon);
          $('#player-TheProspector').text(TheProspector);
          $('#player-Crimson').text(Crimson);
          $('#player-Borealis').text(Borealis);
          $('#player-PolarisLance').text(PolarisLance);
          $('#player-IzanagisBurden').text(IzanagisBurden);
          $('#player-Sunshot').text(Sunshot);
          $('#player-Arbalest').text(Arbalest);
          $('#player-WhisperoftheWorm').text(WhisperoftheWorm);
          $('#player-LegendofAcrius').text(LegendofAcrius);
          $('#player-TheLastWord').text(TheLastWord);
          $('#player-MIDAMulti-Tool').text(MIDAMulti - Tool);
          $('#player-Wish-Ender').text(Wish - Ender);
          $('#player-Jötunn').text(Jötunn);
          $('#player-Malfeasance').text(Malfeasance);
          $('#player-PrometheusLens').text(PrometheusLens);
          $('#player-OutbreakPerfected').text(OutbreakPerfected);
          $('#player-Truth').text(Truth);
          $('#player-Coldheart').text(Coldheart);
          $('#player-Cerberus+').text(Cerberus);
          $('#player-WorldlineZero').text(WorldlineZero);
          $('#player-BadJuju').text(BadJuju);
          $('#player-Riskrunner').text(Riskrunner);
          $('#player-Thunderlord').text(Thunderlord);
          $('#player-Sturm').text(Sturm);
          $('#player-LordofWolves').text(LordofWolves);
          $('#player-FightingLion').text(FightingLion);
          $('#player-TractorCannon').text(TractorCannon);
          $('#player-VigilanceWing').text(VigilanceWing);
        } else {
          alert('Uh oh, failed to load player stats! Looks like Bungie\'s doing server maintenance or having problems. Please check back again soon!');
          console.log(data);
        }

      },
      error: function(data) {
        alert('Uh oh, failed to load player stats! Looks like Bungie\'s doing server maintenance or having problems. Please check back again soon!');
        console.log('Error loading player stats:', data);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

This is the error code :
[image]

```js
"Response": {
  "weapons": [{
        "referenceId": 2208405142,
        "values": {
          "uniqueWeaponAssists": {
            "statId": "uniqueWeaponAssists",
            "basic": {
              "value": 0.0,
              "displayValue": "0"
            }
          },
          "uniqueWeaponAssistDamage": {
            "statId": "uniqueWeaponAssistDamage",
            "basic": {
              "value": 0.0,
              "displayValue": "0"
            }
          },
          "uniqueWeaponKills": {
            "statId": "uniqueWeaponKills",
            "basic": {
              "value": 2069.0,
              "displayValue": "2069"
            }
          },
          "uniqueWeaponPrecisionKills": {
            "statId": "uniqueWeaponPrecisionKills",
            "basic": {
              "value": 0.0,
              "displayValue": "0"
            }
          },
          "uniqueWeaponKillsPrecisionKills": {
            "statId": "uniqueWeaponKillsPrecisionKills",
            "basic": {
              "value": 0.0,
              "displayValue": "0%"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "referenceId": 2286143274,
        "values": {
          "uniqueWeaponAssists": {
            "statId": "uniqueWeaponAssists",
            "basic": {
              "value": 0.0,
              "displayValue": "0"
            }
          },
          "uniqueWeaponAssistDamage": {
            "statId": "uniqueWeaponAssistDamage",
            "basic": {
              "value": 0.0,
              "displayValue": "0"
            }
          },
          "uniqueWeaponKills": {
            "statId": "uniqueWeaponKills",
            "basic": {
              "value": 1529.0,
              "displayValue": "1529"
            }
          },
          "uniqueWeaponPrecisionKills": {
            "statId": "uniqueWeaponPrecisionKills",
            "basic": {
              "value": 532.0,
              "displayValue": "532"
            }
          },
          "uniqueWeaponKillsPrecisionKills": {
            "statId": "uniqueWeaponKillsPrecisionKills",
            "basic": {
              "value": 0.34793982995421846,
              "displayValue": "35%"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "referenceId": 2362471601,
        "values": {
          "uniqueWeaponAssists": {
            "statId": "uniqueWeaponAssists",
            "basic": {
              "value": 0.0,
              "displayValue": "0"
            }
          },
          "uniqueWeaponAssistDamage": {
            "statId": "uniqueWeaponAssistDamage",
            "basic": {
              "value": 0.0,
              "displayValue": "0"
            }
          },
          "uniqueWeaponKills": {
            "statId": "uniqueWeaponKills",
            "basic": {
              "value": 169.0,
              "displayValue": "169"
            }
          },
          "uniqueWeaponPrecisionKills": {
            "statId": "uniqueWeaponPrecisionKills",
            "basic": {
              "value": 57.0,
              "displayValue": "57"
            }
          },
          "uniqueWeaponKillsPrecisionKills": {
            "statId": "uniqueWeaponKillsPrecisionKills",
            "basic": {
              "value": 0.33727810650887574,
              "displayValue": "34%"
            }
          }
        }
      },
```

This is a Sample of the Json response Im simply trying to make the https request, and then parse it into dot notation in a java script file, and then call the objects in html.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you are ether trying to access values before its been created because of asynchronous ajax or you are just not accessing the JSON correctly. I would recommend opening the chrome debugger and putting some break points in to follow the data.

Comment: Would that explain why it doesn't always do it on the same line though?

Comment: `values` seems to be a property of a weapon, so it seems that this may be happening whenever a particular weapon does not exist (or does not exist yet).

Comment: I think that is correct, do you have any Idea how I could fix that?